# PHP MySQL Updating in a Form Is not Updating

Tags: php, mysql, forms, updating

So this is for a school project. We are making a website and I am using PHP with MySQL and phpMyAdmin.
My problem is that when I am updating a product instead of changing the field, it erases all the data for the row besides the ProductID, which is the primary key.
***EDIT: I will address this here: This is a school project and thus security is not an issue for me.
I just need the products to update, now. The erasing problem has been solved.
** End Edit **
Code: 
update-page.php - has the actual form in it

```
 <'?'php
 session_start();

 require_once 'db_connect.php';

 $query = "SELECT * FROM Products";

 $result = mysql_query($query);

 if (!$result) {
 die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
 }
 $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

 <head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>AppleRetail - Update Product</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/update-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

 </head>

 <body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">AppleRetail.com</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="products-page.php">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="add-page.php">Add Product</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="delete-page.php">Delete Product</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="update-page.php">Update Price</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- Jumbotron Header -->
    <header class="jumbotron hero-spacer">
        <h1>Update Product</h1>
        <p>Change the information below and select "Update" to update the product information.</p>
    </header>

    <hr>
<form action="update.php" method="POST">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Image URL</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
            <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['ProductID']; ?>"/>
                <td><?php echo $row['ProductID']; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['Name']; ?>"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $row['Description']; ?>"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['Price']; ?>"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="image" value="<?php echo $row['Image']; ?>"/></td>
                <td>
                 <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
                </td>
            </tr>
    <?php }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>Copyright &copy; AppleRetail.com</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And then the update.php has the query in it.

```
 <?php
  session_start();

  require_once 'db_connect.php';

 // Grab the posted data and send to variable
 $ProductID = $_POST['ProductID'];
 $Name = $_POST['Name'];
 $Description = $_POST['Description'];
 $Price = $_POST['Price'];
 $Image = $_POST['Image'];

 $_SESSION['ProductId1'] =$ProductId;
 $_SESSION['Name1'] = $Name;
 $_SESSION['Description1'] = $Description;
 $_SESSION['Price1'] = $Price;
 $_SESSION['Image1'] = $Image;

  $query = "UPDATE Products SET Name='$Name', Description='$Description', Price='$Price', Image='$Image' WHERE ProductID='$ProductID'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  if (!$result) {
   die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
  }

  if($result =='true'){echo "<p>Post is add</p>";}
  else{ echo "<p>Post is not add</p>"; }
 ?>

  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AppleRetail Update Page</title>
  </head>
 <body>
 <?php header("Location: updateFinal.php"); ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Any Help is appreciated! Thank you!
Please ask if more information is needed!

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @JayBlanchard This is just a school project. No one is going to be using it. It's all fake. And for the functions, it's how the teacher taught and what I'm supposed to be using.

Answer (score 1):

```
input type="text" name="name"
input type="text" name="description"
```

Compare that with

```
$_POST['Name'];
        ^
$_POST['Description'];
        ^
```

And spot the error ;)

Comment: that fixed the erasing of data, but it still doesn't update anything